# why printf output zero for a non-zero double?

Tags: c++, windows, printf

I have a piece of code:
Under `Windows MSVC 2012`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


namespace myname{
    double var = 42;
}

extern "C" double _ZN6myname3varE = 10.0;

int main(){
    printf("%d\n", _ZN6myname3varE);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is `0`. But I think the output should be `10`. Could you help explain why?

Comment: `d` -> `f` ....

Comment: I'm not sure *what* you wanted that to be, but it's a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: Voting to put on hold as the problem described is caused by a simple misunderstanding (%d instead of %f).

Comment: @Mysticial What do you mean? Do you printf will convert int to double/float?

Comment: @Mysticial I know your meaning. But I want to know why 0 is output? How this happen?

Comment: %d says: grab four bytes off the stack, treat them as an int, print the decimal representation of that int. You pass a double to the function; the compiler pushes 8 bytes representing that double onto the stack. It just so happens that four low-order bytes of the binary representation of the double value 10.0 are all zeros.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I thought the printf will convert double argument to int (10.0 to 10), and then will output the converted argument. Why printf does not convert argument but just grad the lower 4 bytes?

Comment: @Zack, It's officially undefined behaviour. `printf` has no knowledge of the type of variable you pass in other than what you tell it. `std::cout` is better for that.

Comment: @chris When the function argument type is not the same as parameter type, undefined behaviour happens? It seems that compile will help convert the arguments to desired type of parameter.

Comment: @Zack, Read about how C variadic arguments work. You have to literally put the type, e.g., `int`, that is the next in the list. How does it know which is next in the list? You tell it with the format specifiers. If you say it's an `int`, it will try to pull an `int`, when it's really a `double`. There is no way for the compiler to know what the next one's supposed to be. Variadic templates do the same in C++11, but are type safe.

Comment: @Zack: Compiler do not parse and find the kind of datatypes we have given inside the `printf`'s `char* format`. It happens in runtime only.

Comment: This is the danger of preferring a C solution to a C++ solution. This wouldn't have happened with `cout`. `printf` is unable to do type checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for "*But I want to know why 0 is output? How this happen?*".

`double` is 64-bit and `int` is `32-bit`. When `double` is truncated to `int` (because of using `%d`), only first `4` bytes stored in the memory location of `double` is taken into the `int` value.

Here, value of `double _ZN6myname3varE` is `10.0`, which is `0x4024000000000000` in hex and stored as `00000000 00002440` in memory (little endian). So, when truncated to `int`, only 4 byte LSB is taken which is obviously `zero`.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d\n", _ZN6myname3varE);
```

`%d` should be changed to `%f`, which prints type `double`

But there's another problem: **name mangling**. When I tested the program in gcc, it shows an error:

> Error: symbol `_ZN6myname3varE' is already defined

The problem is the name `_ZN6myname3varE` is a reserved identifier in C++ because it begins with underscore and an uppercase letter.